# is marklogic xcc available for .net dnx core 5.0?

Tags: asp.net-core, marklogic, dnx50

We are trying to build .net Asp.net 5 application that will target dnxcore50.
it will be running on linux platform.

Is  marklogic xcc for net compatible with dnx core 5.0?

Comment: Probably you'll have more changes getting a correct answer by sending a message to MarkLogic... Also, you could just try it to see if it works :) Btw, I have a feeling that it will not work simply because they distribute the library in an archive

Comment: I asked around but didn't find anybody who knew. I'll echo Victor... please try it and let us know if it works!